# Removing single and multiple spaces from textfile java but it should not combine all the lines in text file

Tags: java, file-io

Consider there are n number of lines in txt file,Will give eg for 4 lines.

## Input from file:

> A      B     C     D     E
>
> F   G      H      I       J         K
>
> L     M          N   O    P
>
> Q          R    S      T

## Expected output file:

> ABCDE
>
> FGHIJK
>
> LMNOP
>
> QRST

The output that I manage to produce is:

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST

Expected output should be displayed as shown below, without any space in between words or between lines.

Comment: Can you please share you code?

Answer (score 0):

I want to know if you iterate your text file on each line ? or all as a block ? 
if you are iterating each line then it's simple:

1. Create an empty text variable
2. Assign to this variable the current line you read then apply your space removing function or method to this variable.
3. Now concatinate this variable like this :

   varaible += "\r\n"

this will add a return to new line for each line you removed its spaces

4. that's all.

Comment: String line;
 List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

 while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
//     line = line.replaceAll("\t", "");  
//     line = line.replaceAll("\n", "");  
//     line = line.replaceAll(" ", ""); 
     line = line.replaceAll("[\\s\\u00A0]+",""); 
     
     System.out.println("\n");
     lines.add(line);
     System.out.println(line);
     
//   writer.write(line);
   writer.write(line);
//   fos.write(line);

Comment: yes i want iterate on each line, will try this. thanks a lot:)

Comment: Hello again,
I tried your code, to write text in a file, i used **FileOutputStream** and **BufferedWriter**
then I added this line after this line `line = line.replaceAll("[\\s\\u00A0]+",""); `:
`line += "\r\n";` 
and it worked for me

Comment: this is a clean code:
`File fout = new File("out.txt");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
String line;
while..
line = "ABCDEF\t GHIJ KLMN \n \r";
System.out.println("ligne normale:"+line);
line = line.replaceAll("\t", "");
line = line.replaceAll("\n", "");
line = line.replaceAll(" ", "");
line = line.replaceAll("[\\s\\u00A0]+","");
line += "\r\n";
 bw.write(line);
bw.close();
 `

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method and at the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class. You can use [regex](https://regexone.com/) in order to get rid of the spaces:

```
System.out.println("A B C D E".replaceAll("\\s", ""));  // ABCDE
```

where

> \s    A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]

What you can do is to iterate over each line and remove spaces using the above code. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, based on your problem, it would be most beneficial if you could read line by line. Fortunately, with Java-8's implementation of Streams, you can do that!

The method, will add every line of the file as a **`String`**, into an **`ArrayList<String>`**.

```
static ArrayList<String> readFileText (String filename){

    //ArrayList to hold all the lines
    ArrayList<String> lines = null;
    //Get lines of text (Strings) as a stream
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))){
        // convert stream to a List-type object
        lines = (ArrayList<String>)stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("\nCould not read lines of text from the file.");
    }
    catch (SecurityException se){
        System.out.println("Could not read the file provided." + 
          "Please check if you have permission to access it.");
    }

    return lines;
}
```

By using the above method, you will manage to add every line from the text file, as a `String` in an arraylist, but we still have to remove the whitespaces from each String now.

So, a very simplistic way of doing that, is to write the output file with the following method:

```
static void writeFileText (String filename, ArrayList<String> linesOfText){
        // Specify file location and name
        Path file = Paths.get(filename);
        // StringBuilder will be used to create ONE string of text
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Iterate over the list of strings and append them 
        // to string-builder with a 'new line' carriage return.
        for( String line : linesOfText){
            line.replaceAll(" ", ""); // Replace all whitespace with empty string
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        // Get all bytes of produced string and instantly write them to the file.
        byte[] bytes = sb.toString().getBytes();
        // Write to file
        try{
            Files.write(file, bytes);
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("\nCould not write to file \""+filename+"\".);
        }

}
```

Then your main method would be just 2 lines long (considering that you simply what to solve the problem you posted, and nothing more):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<String> lines = Class.readFileText("input.txt");
    Class.writeFileText("output.txt", lines);
}
```

Here, **Class** refers to the class name, where the static methods reside.

> The above methods were taken from [this](https://github.com/soutzis/Ciphers-Key-Exchange) GitHub repository.